# OPOS - Issue claiming a scanner Honeywell Xenon 1902

Tags: opos

I'm brand new to OPOS and I was hoping you could help me out.
I'm trying to interface to a Honeywell Xenon 1902 and I have no problems opening but every time I try to claim I get OPOS_E_ILLEGAL.  This happens through a short winform script or using Honeywell's validation utility.  I've downloaded "Honeywell OPOS Suite version 1.13.4.17" which I'm assuming contains the proper SO.  Am I forgetting a simple essential step?

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this, the easy way to get you up and running is for you to open the Configuration Utility that was installed as part of the Honeywell Suite. Add your device there (or modify if you already created one), set Auto Detect to false, and then select the COM port that matches your device in your Device Manager. Then fire up Honeywell's Validation Utility and try to claim your device again.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, it turns out Honeywell's Configuration Utility didn't work with the SurePOS protocol despite the claims in the documentation.  Toshiba's configurator seemed to work though.

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I programmed the scanner to use IBM's SurePOS USB protocol and when using Honeywell's OPOS Config it would return OPOS_E_ILLEGAL.

When the scanner configuration was changed to USB COM, the claim worked. If using SurePOS is a necessity, removing the Honeywell drivers and installing IBM (now Toshiba's) OPOS driver worked as well.